# How to pass String array in @RequestParam in REST GET API call through POSTMAN or DHC REST application?

Tags: spring-boot, postman, http-request-parameters

I have following REST controller in Java Spring Application:

```
@RequestMapping(
     value = "/api/getApplication/{me_userId}", 
     method = RequestMethod.GET, 
     produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Object getApplication(
        @PathVariable String userId,
        @RequestParam(value="fieldNames[]", required = false) String[] fieldNames) {

            if (fieldNames != null) {
                for (String fieldName : fieldNames)
                    System.out.println(fieldName);
            }

            ...
            return null;
}
```

So I can not succeed in simulating API call from DHC REST of POSTMAN what will pass that fieldNames[].

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: There is a typo: @PathVariable String should be - me_userId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your current method does not work because your `@PathVariable` is wrong. In your `@RequestMapping` you have the following placeholder in your path: `{me_userId}`, which means that it will be mapped to a path variable with that name.

However, the only `@PathVariable` you have is nameless, which means it will use the name of the parameter (userId) in stead.

So before you try to execute your request, you have to change your `@RequestMapping` into:

```java
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/api/getApplication/{userId}", // <-- it's now {userId}
    method = RequestMethod.GET, 
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Then, if you run the application, you can kinda choose how you want to pass your parameters. Both the following will work:

```java
?fieldNames[]=test,test2
```

Or:

```java
?fieldNames[]=test&fieldNames[]=test2
```

Both these results should print the desired results.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it is a typo, it should be me_userId in a @PathVariable String

Comment: And, yes, Thank you very much your solutions work, so we basically have to append the array with variables to URL. That is fine, it works for me!